# Cordova not adding capabilities to appxmanifest file

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, taco

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2) to build an app using Apache Cordova. This app uses the `cordova-plugin-media` plugin for recording audio. However, when I try to record audio, I get this error: `Access is denied`.

Looking at the generated `package.windows10.appxmanifest` file in `\platforms\windows`, I don't see the `microphone` capability in there. There's is only one capability:

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
```

So the microphone capability is missing. However, this is what I find in `windows.json`:

```
"config_munge": {
    "files": {
        "package.appxmanifest": {
            "parents": {
                "/Package/Capabilities": [
                    {
                        "xml": "<DeviceCapability Name=\"microphone\" />",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to make sure this capability is properly added to the generated manifest(s)? Notice the different name: `package.appxmanifest` in `windows.json`, whereare the generated manifest is actually `package.windows10.appxmanifest`.

This is with Cordova 6.1.1 and Cordova@Windows 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was affected by [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10845) in `cordova-windows@4.3.1` which prevented capabilities in the manifest file from being updated.

The issue has been resolved as of [`cordova-windows@4.3.2`](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/04/05/cordova-windows-4.3.2.html), which was release April 5th.

Comment: I have the latest one but still, there is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to add the capability:

1. Add `<DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />` inside Capabilities tag of your `package.windows10.appxmanifest` file like this:

   ```
   <Capabilities>
     <Capability Name="internetClient" />
     <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
   </Capabilities>
   ```
2. Navigate to the root folder of your project. Open command line window and type in `cordova platform update windows` command to update the windows platform. `<DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />` will be added to the mannifest file.

Comment: Hi, that definitely helped me out. Turns out there was a bug in the `cordova-windows` package, which has been solved in the latest version.